# how to close websocket connection when empty response is received in JMeter

Tags: websocket, connection, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Websocket plugin provided in [JMeter-WebsocketPlugin](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/cloud-based-jmeter-websocket-testing/).
In my test, Websocket connection should be closed when there is a empty response or when [Frame] is not received as response, in this case what would be the pattern for "WebSocket Response - Close connection pattern:"

I tried giving a space but did not work, please find the screenshots.
[image]
[image: Websocket is opened]

Comment: Please post the response.